# Bundle Error on macOS 10.12 Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, macos-sierra

```
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-9.0.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.6
Ignoring capybara-webkit-1.11.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine capybara-webkit --version 1.11.1
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-9.0.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.6
Ignoring capybara-webkit-1.11.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine capybara-webkit --version 1.11.1
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
Ignoring eventmachine-1.2.0.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.2.0.1
Ignoring eventmachine-1.0.9.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.0.9.1
Ignoring ffi-1.9.14 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.14
Ignoring http_parser.rb-0.6.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine http_parser.rb --version 0.6.0
Ignoring io-console-0.4.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine io-console --version 0.4.6
Ignoring json-2.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 2.0.2
Ignoring kgio-2.10.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine kgio --version 2.10.0
Ignoring mysql2-0.4.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.4.4
Ignoring nio4r-1.2.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 1.2.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.8.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.8.1
Ignoring pg-0.19.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg --version 0.19.0
Ignoring psych-2.1.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine psych --version 2.1.1
Ignoring puma-3.6.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine puma --version 3.6.0
Ignoring raindrops-0.17.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine raindrops --version 0.17.0
Ignoring rgeo-0.5.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine rgeo --version 0.5.3
Ignoring rmagick-2.16.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine rmagick --version 2.16.0
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.11
Ignoring therubyracer-0.12.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine therubyracer --version 0.12.2
Ignoring thin-1.5.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine thin --version 1.5.1
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.2
Ignoring unicorn-5.1.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unicorn --version 5.1.0
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.6.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.6.4
The git source `git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
The git source `git://github.com/jetthoughts/yaml_db.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reinstall the version of Ruby you're using (via rbenv, rvm, etc.) and then run `gem pristine --all` to rebuild any gems using native extensions.

Comment: Thanks you soo much :)

Comment: Thank you: it is still true on Tuesday October 16, 2018.